# R GLM/GLMER Differences in Intercepts Due to Group-level Variance

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I've been playing with simulated multilevel data and came across something that I can't find the answer to. I find it instructive to demonstrate that logic of multilevel modeling by first getting estimates for each group and then going from there.  For a normally distributed outcome in the intercept-only model (and assuming equal group size), the MLM intercept is equal to the mean of the group intercepts. For a binary outcome, however, the issue is more complicated. The mean of the intercepts (e.g., the log odds of success) equals the MLM intercept when group variance is 0 but does not as group variance for the log odds increases. But I'm not sure what the rate is or how to express it. I've read Hox, Heck and Thomas, and Gelman and Hill, as well as searched the web, but can't find what I'm looking for.

Code below--I use the simr package to create the dataframes (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/vignettes/fromscratch.html
).

```
set.seed(1234)

#create df structure
X <- expand.grid(x=1:50, grp=letters[1:15])

#binomial, group var = .01
dat1 <- simr::makeGlmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), family="binomial", fixef=1, VarCorr=.01, data=X)

#binomial, group var = 1
dat2 <- simr::makeGlmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), family="binomial", fixef=1, VarCorr=1, data=X)

## normal, group var and residual (sigma) = 1
dat3 <- simr::makeLmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), fixef=1, VarCorr=1, sigma=1, data=X)


#glm model dat1
level1.1 <- glm(y ~ 1, family = "binomial", data = dat1@frame)

#glmer model dat1
level2.1 <- lme4::glmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), family = "binomial", data = dat1@frame)

#glm model dat2
level1.2 <- glm(y ~ 1, family = "binomial", data = dat2@frame)

#glmer model dat2
level2.2 <- lme4::glmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), family = "binomial", data = dat2@frame)

#lm model dat3
level1.3 <- lm(y ~ 1, data = dat3@frame )

#lmer model dat2
level2.3 <- lme4::lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|grp), data = dat3@frame)
```

Table of estimates (using screenreg). Notice the estimates for Model 2 are different for glm and glmer.

```
======================================================================================================
                      Model 1 GLM  Model 1 GLMER  Model 2 GLM  Model 2 GLMER  Model 3 LM  Model 2 LMER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)              0.87 ***     0.87 ***       0.75 ***     0.90 **       0.78 ***      0.78 ** 
                        (0.08)       (0.08)         (0.08)       (0.29)        (0.05)        (0.27)   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                    911.42       913.42         942.30       831.87                     2128.65    
BIC                    916.04       922.66         946.92       841.11                     2142.51    
Log Likelihood        -454.71      -454.71        -470.15      -413.94                    -1061.32    
Deviance               909.42                      940.30                                             
Num. obs.              750          750            750          750           750           750       
Num. groups: grp                     15                          15                          15       
Var: grp (Intercept)                  0.00                        1.09                        1.08    
R^2                                                                             0.00                  
Adj. R^2                                                                        0.00                  
RMSE                                                                            1.39                  
Var: Residual                                                                                 0.91    
======================================================================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Finally, here's code that produces glms for each group in dat2 and computes the mean of the intercepts. That mean equals the intercept estimate for the GLMER version of Model 2.

```
dat1@frame %>%
  nest(data=-grp) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ glm(y ~ 1, family = binomial, data = .)),
         results = map(fit, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(results) %>% 
  summarize(mean.int = mean(estimate))
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here.

Comment: Ok.  Why is the intercept for multilevel logistic regression different from glm (without nesting) when group variance does not equal zero? As a point of comparison, for a normally distributed outcome, the lm intercept equals the multilevel one even with substantial group-level variance.  I want to understand why the intercepts are different for multilevel logistic regression compared to a comparable glm.

Comment: The expected value of a nonlinear function doesn't equal the function applied to the expected value. Your link function isn't linear right?

Comment: Thanks.  Thought about that but wasn't quite sure.  Should I repost there or link this?  Which is preferred?

Comment: Repost is preferred, rather than duplicate posts. I've flagged this one for migration already, so it may get migrated for you shortly. Alternatively, you could could do it yourself by deleting this post and putting it up at CV. Thanks!